# bourne shell, editing file, with specific column and row

Tags: bash, shell, sh

I am trying to write the current date to a file.
I want to write it to the 2nd row 2nd column (columns are seperated by ';')

**Using Shell**

What I tried so far, Not Working:

```
paste <(echo "$(date)") <(awk -F ";" '{print $2}' file)
```

Is there any smart way to do so?

example 'file':

```
John;Wed Mar 14 19:41:38 CET 2018;18
Sandra;Mon Mar 14 19:41:38 CET 2018;21
David;Sun Mar 14 19:41:38 CET 2018;25
```

example after editing 'file':

```
John;Wed Mar 14 19:41:38 CET 2018;18
Sandra;The Date When Editing The File With Script;21
David;Sun Mar 14 19:41:38 CET 2018;25
```

Comment: Arrays? Also, please,read how to [ask good questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Eh? `<(...)` isn't even allowed in (1990s-era) POSIX sh, much less 1970s-era Bourne. It's a ksh extension adopted by bash. (And are you **really** using Bourne? It was sorta-common into the mid-2000s on account of SunOS shipping it even after everyone else had switched to POSIX-compliant `sh` implementations, but even that's a decade ago now).

Comment: it is just for school purpose...

Answer (score 3):

To replace the second row second column with the current date:

```
$ awk -F";" -v d="$(date)" 'NR==2{$2=d} 1' OFS=";" file
John;Wed Mar 14 19:41:38 CET 2018;18
Sandra;Wed Mar 14 13:28:59 PDT 2018;21
David;Sun Mar 14 19:41:38 CET 2018;25
```

#### How it works

- `-F";"`

  This tells awk to use `;` as the field separator.
- `-v d="$(date)"`

  This defines an awk variable `d` that contains the current date.
- `NR==2{$2=d}`

  On the second row, `NR==2`, this tells awk to replace the second column, `$2`, with that value of variable `d`.
- `1`

  This is awk's shorthand for print-the-current-line.
- `OFS=";"`

  This tells awk to use `;` as the field separator on output.

#### Modifying the file in-place

To modify the file in-place using a modern GNU awk:

```
gawk -i inplace -F";" -v d="$(date)" 'NR==2{$2=d} 1' OFS=";" file
```

To modify the file using macOS or BSD or older GNU awk:

```
awk -F";" -v d="$(date)" 'NR==2{$2=d} 1' OFS=";" file >tmp && mv tmp file
```

#### Matters of style

The following three lines are all equivalent.  Which one you use is a matter of style:

```
awk -F";" -v d="$(date)" 'NR==2{$2=d} 1' OFS=";" file
awk -F";" -v d="$(date)" -v OFS=";" 'NR==2{$2=d} 1' file
awk -F";" 'NR==2{$2=d} 1'  d="$(date)" OFS=";" file
```

Comment: To write the result back to the original file: `gawk -i inplace -F...` -- see https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Extension-Sample-Inplace.html

Comment: Why do you use both `-v` and set OFS after the script body? One or the other style?

Comment: @glennjackman I added a GNU `-i inplace` example although we do have to be careful when recommending it because there are still old versions of GNU awk in use (_e.g._ Ubuntu 14) that don't support `-i inplace`.

Comment: @glennjackman I find that style that I used makes it easy for me to read the code from left-to-right.  One needs to know the value of `d` before it is used in an assignment while `OFS` affects only the final output.  But, you are absolutely that other styles are possible and other people may prefer those other styles.  I added to the end of the answer some options showing different styles.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this one:

```
sed "2s/\(^[^\;]*\;[^\;]*\)/\1\;`date`/" <filename>
```